# syntax issue on php 7.4

Tags: php, functions, pages, dashboard

I have a syntex issue on my WordPress platform since I tried to put php version on 7.4.

WordPress sent me automated email with the error below :

## Error Details

An error of type E_PARSE was caused in line 12 of the file /public_html/wp-content/themes/bb-theme-child/companies.php. 
**Error message: syntax error, unexpected 'fn' (T_FN), expecting '('**

I put here the beginning of the file companies.php code and the line 12 is : **function fn($function)**

```
<?php

namespace DisplaceTech\Companies;

/**
 * Wrap function names for the namespace.
 *
 * @param string $function
 *
 * @return string
 */
function fn($function)
{
    return '\DisplaceTech\Companies\\' . $function;
}

/**
 * Add the Clients metabox to the Proposal page.
 */
function add_clients_metabox()
{
    $screens = ['page'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'clients',              // Unique ID
            __('Clients'),          // Box title
            fn('clients_box_html'), // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                // Post type
            'advanced',             // Context
            'high'                  // Priority
        );
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', fn('add_clients_metabox'));
```

NOTE: the platform works with php 7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**

Have you tried changing the function name? something similar **function getClientFn($function){}**? You can keep any name you want.

```
function getClientFn($function){
    return '\DisplaceTech\Companies\\' . $function;
}

function add_clients_metabox(){
    $screens = ['page'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'clients',              // Unique ID
            __('Clients'),          // Box title
            getClientFn('clients_box_html'), // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                // Post type
            'advanced',             // Context
            'high'                  // Priority
        );
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_clients_metabox');
```

**Option 2:** If you really need to keep 'fn' method, then give a try with below script which works in php 7.4.

```
$myfunction = fn($function) => '\DisplaceTech\Companies\\' . $function;

function add_clients_metabox(){
    $screens = ['page'];
    foreach ($screens as $screen) {
        add_meta_box(
            'clients',              // Unique ID
            __('Clients'),          // Box title
            $myfunction('clients_box_html'), // Content callback, must be of type callable
            $screen,                // Post type
            'advanced',             // Context
            'high'                  // Priority
        );
    } } add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_clients_metabox');
```

Comment: yes but it doesn't work

Comment: make sure to replace 'fn' with your new name in all appropriate places. I tried the same and it worked for me. I think you need to replace it in two more places fn('clients_box_html') & fn('add_clients_metabox')

Comment: what you put exactly to make it work please? in my case it still not working

Comment: @sampaii modified answer with the script I used. You can give a try.

Comment: Thanks for the Help :)

Comment: @sampaii you're welcome!